# Получить ссылку на изображение с яндекс картинок C#

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Есть приложение, в котором пользователь может просматривать через webbrowser изображения на яндекс картинках, а затем скачивать понравившиеся. До этого момента прямую ссылку на изображение можно было получить следующим образом:

```
urlImage = HD.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@class='MMButton MMButton_type_link MMViewerButtons-OpenImage MMViewerButtons-OpenImage_isOtherSizesEnabled']").GetAttributeValue("href", "");
```

Но теперь код возвращает "#". При этом, если смотреть исходный код страницы через тот же Хром, в этом классе как раз хранится ссылка на изображение. Я подумал, что это недочет webbrowser, ведь он не очень дружит со скриптами, поэтому сначала установил awesomium, но в нем изображения даже не открывались при клике на них, а затем поставил cefsharp. В нем изображение открывается, но в исходном коде страницы в атрибуте href тоже отображается "#". Подскажите, что можно сделать?
Использую winforms-версию.

Исходный код получал так:

```
public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;

....

string html = await chromeBrowser.GetSourceAsync();
```

Comment: 1. На кой черт вам тут вообще браузер? Создали UI с нужным видом (что вам надо, вывести картинку, мб ее описание, ну и кнопку "скачать"), сделали класс с этими всеми свойствами, зашли на сайт, взяли картинки, заполнили `List<Класс>`, вывели, все... Зачем же вам тут тонна бессмысленного мусора сдалась в виде awsomium и его аналогов? 2. Сайт использует API, вы не получаете контент в HTML, он генерируется. Работайте с API напрямую, получайте в ответ JSON и разбирайте его.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ разве у яндекса API картинок имеется? Или вы о том, чтобы отправлять запрос с параметрами на /images/search (другой страницы подходящей не вижу)?

Comment: Покрутите страницу, будут подгружаться картинки новые автоматом? От куда он берет эти данные, как думаете? Наверно с [API](https://yandex.ru/collections/api/user/feed?source_name=collections&ui=desktop&type=general)?) А если вы откроете картинку, то получите ссылку, примерно такого вида `https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/49816/e764985b-dfc4-4b9a-b963-922db68dd7d6`, значения для которой можете получить в [API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0U6i.png).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я правильно понимаю, что здесь вы говорите про коллекции https://yandex.ru/collections/ ? С ними я понял, как это работает, спасибо, но я имел ввиду, что мне нужны изображения со страницы https://yandex.ru/images/ Там я вижу только запрос на адрес /images/search?callback=jQuery*здесь циферки и куча параметров*

Comment: С указанной страницей чуть сложнее: Сайт отдает вам страницу, которая имеет "заготовку" и контент в виде JSON, который потом она обрабатывает. Сам контент находится в HTML, а конкретней `<script type="application/json" id="restoreData">`. А вот собственно что [вы получаете](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJWlb.png), то есть пустая страница и скорей всего из за этого вы не можете получить нужный контент. При прокрутке вроде как также идет отправка запроса к API (не точно), можете покопаться в нем, может он отдает стартовые значения тоже.